# Passing vector string to parameter vector array

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I create a vector string v and pass this vector to parameter with vector string array, I got an compiler error: no matching function for call.

**My Function**

```
int functionA(vector <string> &a) //vector <string>  &a[] could not work
{}
```

**Calling function in main:**

```
vector <string> a;
for(int i =0 ; i < a.size(); i++)
{
 functionA(a[i]); //Error at this line...
}
```

functionA(a) should works but I want to use the array in the vector string. How can I do that ?

Comment: You would like to pass just a string or vector of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to pass

A) `vector` of `strings`

Call:

```
vector <string> a;
..
..    
functionA(a); //notice this is not in for loop.
```

Function Signature:

```
int functionA(vector <string> &a)
```

B) only `string`.

call:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i < (unsigned int)a.size();i++)
   functionA(a.at(i));
```

Function Signature:

```
int functionA(string &a)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int functionA(vector <string> &a)
```

is a function that takes reference to `vector<string>` so you need to pass a vector to it:

```
vector <string> a;
...
functionA(a);
```

`a[i]` in your code is `std::string`, not a vector.

---

But if you want to pass a single string, then keep that loop and keep passing `a[i]`, just change the function to:

```
int functionA(std::string& str)
```